# What is the Elixir idiom for streaming data to a file in text format with guaranteed closing?

Tags: elixir

I have written some code to generate stream of values and I want to send these to a text file for analysis. I know how to open a file using

```
   { f, :ok } = File.open( 'foobar', [ :write, :utf8 ] )
```

but I can't find a way of sending the stream to this file, even though I'm sure this must be trivial.

Since this is potentially quite a large amount of data, I'd like to avoid the use of intermediate data structures and stick to the streaming approach. If possible, I'd also like to have some way of guaranteeing that the file will get closed, even in the event of errors.

Answer (score 3):

Streams are created using `File.stream!`. You don't need to explicitly close a stream as their file is automatically opened and closed by Elixir every time you [start](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/77ae863bd02ca90496b96854249b8942ac76b8b4/lib/elixir/lib/file/stream.ex#L41)/[stop](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/77ae863bd02ca90496b96854249b8942ac76b8b4/lib/elixir/lib/file/stream.ex#L59)/[halt](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/77ae863bd02ca90496b96854249b8942ac76b8b4/lib/elixir/lib/file/stream.ex#L64) streaming data into it.

> Note that the file is automatically opened each time streaming begins.

[Source](http://elixir-lang.org/docs/stable/elixir/File.html#stream!/3)

You can use `Enum.into` (or `Stream.into`) to write an enumerable or stream to a File Stream returned by `File.stream!` without storing the values of the enumerable/stream in memory:

```
iex(1)> ["foo", "bar"] |> Enum.into(File.stream!("a.txt"))
%File.Stream{line_or_bytes: :line, modes: [:raw, :read_ahead, :binary],
 path: "a.txt", raw: true}
iex(2)> File.read!("a.txt")
"foobar"
```

Comment: Following you advice I'm now doing my_stream_func() |> Stream.take(5) |> Stream.into(File.stream!("a.txt", [:write, :utf8])). Unfortunately, I'm not getting any new lines between values. How can I add these?

Comment: @Andy you mean like this: `["foo", "bar", "baz"] |> Stream.flat_map(fn a -> [a, "\n"] end) |> Enum.into(File.stream!("a.txt"))`?